# C# - I need to loop through a list and find variables with matching values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, for-loop

Total newb here so please be patient!!

I have a list of airplanes that are mostly different models. However, I need to be able to find ones that are the same models and add their values together. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

List of airplanes:

Plane 1

1. Model: Boeing777
2. Total seats: 200
3. Attendants needed: 4

Plane 2

1. Model: Boeing727
2. Total seats: 150
3. Attendants needed: 3

Plane 3

1. Model: Boeing777
2. Total seats: 200
3. Attendants needed: 4

So, I want to loop through this list of airplanes, and instead of it outputting two Boeing 777s, I want it to output 1 Boeing777, and then total up the seats and attendants needed.

The output would be:

List of airplanes:

1. Model: Boeing777
2. Total seats: 400
3. Attendants needed: 8

   1. Model: Boeing727
   2. Total seats: 150
   3. Attendants needed: 3

Does this make any sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy()`:

```
var groups = planes.GroupBy(p => p.Model);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Model: {0}", group.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("2. Total Seats: {0}", group.Sum(p => p.Seats));
    Console.WriteLine("3. Attendants: {0}", group.Sum(p => p.Attendants));
}
```

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked exactly like I needed it to!